# Problem with dual monitor on 16.04 with lenovo yoga 260

Tags: multiple-monitors, 16.04, intel-graphics, lenovo

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 with Lenovo yoga 260.

When I connect external monitor, it is very unstable.
Problem occurs after login and desktop is successfully booted.

1. It freezes soon after desktop is booted.
2. It works well when I use mouse on the external monitor. But when I move mouse from external monitor to internal monitor, it freezes soon.
3. It seems working well in some time, but  it freezes accidentally.

1st & 3rd is rare case, 2nd case is very often.

When OS freezes, mouse and keyboard are not work and screen is not black screen,but just stops working.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I think the best answer is to refer people to the Lenovo site.  I believe this is a known issue. See, for example:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Lenovo-Yoga-260-and-OneLink-dock-external-display-issue/td-p/3327704

An employee states:

> 11-04-2016 11:30 AM
>
> In response to customer reports of blinking or flickering on external
>   monitors connected to Yoga 260 ThinkPad systems via OneLink+ VGA/RJ45
>   adapter or OneLink+ dock, Lenovo has provided a solution for Yoga 260
>   ThinkPad systems under warranty.
>
> To contact Lenovo Service, please click here and reference Service TIP
>   SF16-T0080/ HT502248. This solution will require the Yoga 260 to be
>   serviced.

However, some users report that it is not a problem with the laptop, but is instead either a bad cable or a bad dock. The discussion above has comments like this:

> for me, this seems to be only a cable issue (at least for now).
>   Problem solved by using a new cable ATM.